# Tomcat 8 Why random requests are very slow?

Tags: java, tomcat

I was running ab benchmarking tool and noticed that some requests take significantly more time to execute.

**100 Requests**

```
ab -n 100 http://test.local:8080/TestApp/

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      1
  66%      1
  75%      1
  80%      1
  90%      1
  95%      2
  98%      8
  99%    304
 100%    304 (longest request)
```

Someone might assume that first request takes longer to execute but it's not the case.

**10 Requests**

```
ab -n 10 http://test.local:8080/TestApp/

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      1
  66%      1
  75%      1
  80%      2
  90%      2
  95%      2
  98%      2
  99%      2
 100%      2 (longest request)
```

My question is: why there are such slow requests (304ms) and how to make sure 100% of requests are always executed in 2ms.

For testing purpose I didn't include any logic to TestApp, only servlet with "test" text output.

Comment: Maybe because of garbage collection.

Comment: you may want to profile your app with some profiler tools, like JProfiler